# Capturing mutiple Data from userform in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `userform` where there are more than 50 data points that are being captured. Mostly user entries and few from other database. I want to transfer them to excel. Is there any better way to do this than writing the below for each data point?

```
Range("A1").Value = TextBox44.Value
```

Comment: You could try the controlsource property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251763.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a for each statement like this:

```
Dim intRow As Integer
intRow = 1
For Each tbTextBox In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(tbTextBox) = "TextBox" Then
        Cells(intRow, 1) = tbTextBox.Value
        intRow = intRow + 1
    End If
Next
```

This is not tested, so there could be some minor errors